# Group rows by same values and return only one?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want my query to return only ONE row (first row) for each unique `LetoZrChr` (so 5 rows total).

Here's what it currently does:

It returns all rows (258) without grouping the information by the column I want it to.

My current SQL:

```
SELECT a.maticna, a.clientNo,  a.letoZr, a.letoZrChr, a.sort, a.tipOcene, a.bonitetniModel, a.datumOtvoritve,
    im.PKModul1_LT as ocm1solor_LT, im.PDModul1_LT*100 as ocm1solo_LT, im.PKModul1_ST as ocm1solor_ST, im.PDModul1_ST*100 as ocm1solo_ST, im.DatumKLJ    
FROM #osnovna a 
LEFT JOIN airb.bm.IzhodModeli im on a.clientNo=im.KomitentID
    AND im.ReferencniDatum=a.datumOtvoritve
    AND a.tipocene = im.tipocene
    --GROUP BY letoZrChr    
ORDER BY datumOtvoritve DESC, im.DatumKLJ DESC
```

The return of this SQL (I've purposely left some rows out, as it returns 258 rows, but you'll get the idea from the rows below):

```
maticna clientNo letoZr letoZrChr   sort    tipOcene    bonitetniModel  datumOtvoritve  ocm1solor_LT    ocm1solo_LT ocm1solor_ST    ocm1solo_ST DatumKLJ
5046432 975145  2019    PL2019  5   3   GD  2019-12-31  NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL
5046432 975145  2019    ML2019  4   2   GD  2019-06-30  4   0,868   3   0,565   43899
5046432 975145  2019    ML2019  4   2   GD  2019-06-30  4   0,868   3   0,565   43898
5046432 975145  2019    ML2019  4   2   GD  2019-06-30  4   0,868   3   0,565   43897
5046432 975145  2019    ML2019  4   2   GD  2019-06-30  4   0,868   3   0,565   43896
5046432 975145  2018    ZR2018  3   1   GD  2018-12-31  7   8,098   6   5,236   43899
5046432 975145  2018    ZR2018  3   1   GD  2018-12-31  7   8,098   6   5,236   43898
5046432 975145  2018    ZR2018  3   1   GD  2018-12-31  7   8,098   6   5,236   43897
5046432 975145  2018    ZR2018  3   1   GD  2018-12-31  7   8,098   6   5,236   43896
5046432 975145  2018    ZR2018  3   1   GD  2018-12-31  7   8,098   6   5,236   43895
5046432 975145  2018    ZR2018  3   1   GD  2018-12-31  7   8,098   6   5,236   43894
5046432 975145  2018    ZR2018  3   1   GD  2018-12-31  7   8,098   6   5,236   43893
5046432 975145  2018    ZR2018  3   1   GD  2018-12-31  7   8,098   6   5,236   43892
5046432 975145  2018    ZR2018  3   1   GD  2018-12-31  7   8,098   6   5,236   43891
5046432 975145  2018    ZR2018  3   1   GD  2018-12-31  7   8,098   6   5,236   43890
5046432 975145  2018    ZR2018  3   1   GD  2018-12-31  6   5,714   5   2,601   43611
5046432 975145  2017    ZR2017  2   1   GD  2017-12-31  6   4,652   5   2,105   43607
5046432 975145  2017    ZR2017  2   1   GD  2017-12-31  6   4,652   5   2,105   43594
5046432 975145  2017    ZR2017  2   1   GD  2017-12-31  6   4,652   5   2,105   43591
5046432 975145  2017    ZR2017  2   1   GD  2017-12-31  6   4,66    5   2,095   43584
5046432 975145  2017    ZR2017  2   1   GD  2017-12-31  6   4,66    5   2,095   43562
5046432 975145  2017    ZR2017  2   1   GD  2017-12-31  6   4,66    5   2,095   43561
5046432 975145  2017    ZR2017  2   1   GD  2017-12-31  6   4,66    5   2,095   43559
5046432 975145  2017    ZR2017  2   1   GD  2017-12-31  6   4,66    5   2,095   43558
5046432 975145  2017    ZR2017  2   1   GD  2017-12-31  6   4,711   5   2,034   43410
5046432 975145  2017    ZR2017  2   1   GD  2017-12-31  6   4,711   5   2,034   43403
5046432 975145  2016    ZR2016  1   1   GD  2016-12-31  5   2,86    NULL    NULL    43244
5046432 975145  2016    ZR2016  1   1   GD  2016-12-31  5   2,86    NULL    NULL    43243
5046432 975145  2016    ZR2016  1   1   GD  2016-12-31  5   2,86    NULL    NULL    43242
5046432 975145  2016    ZR2016  1   1   GD  2016-12-31  5   2,86    NULL    NULL    43241
5046432 975145  2016    ZR2016  1   1   GD  2016-12-31  5   2,86    NULL    NULL    43206
5046432 975145  2016    ZR2016  1   1   GD  2016-12-31  5   2,86    NULL    NULL    43202
5046432 975145  2016    ZR2016  1   1   GD  2016-12-31  5   2,86    NULL    NULL    43201
```

So basically what I want to do is, that the query only returns the first row of each "letoZrChr", which is are for example "ZR2016", or "ML2019", etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand the question correctly, you need to use `ROW_NUMBER()`:

```
SELECT *
FROM (
   SELECT 
      a.maticna, a.clientNo,  a.letoZr, a.letoZrChr, a.sort, a.tipOcene, a.bonitetniModel, a.datumOtvoritve,
      im.PKModul1_LT as ocm1solor_LT, im.PDModul1_LT*100 as ocm1solo_LT, im.PKModul1_ST as ocm1solor_ST, im.PDModul1_ST*100 as ocm1solo_ST, im.DatumKLJ,
      ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY a.letoZrChr ORDER BY datumOtvoritve DESC, im.DatumKLJ DESC) AS rn
   FROM #osnovna a 
   LEFT JOIN 
      airb.bm.IzhodModeli im on a.clientNo=im.KomitentID AND 
      im.ReferencniDatum=a.datumOtvoritve AND 
      a.tipocene = im.tipocene
) t
WHERE t.rn = 1
```